# How to get the total waaagh update?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I've looked at the [patch notes](https://www.totalwar.com/blog/total-war-warhammer-ii-the-total-waaagh-update/), selected the beta and updated my game, it shows in my Steam library:
[image]
However, when I start the game and a greenskin campaign it's the old version. This is especially easy to detect by looking at the Waaagh! status.

Answer (score 1):

Just to try I opted in to the 1.9.0_(live_build), this has made the new campaign and DLC available to me.